# Is there a way to pass parameters to a html file served by node JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express

I wrote an API using Node JS and Express and I have a json file with an array of 150 objects. The API code that sends the entire json looks like this:

```
app.get("/api/pokemons", function (req, res) {
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  let rawdata = fs.readFileSync("assets/pokemons.json");
  let pokemons = JSON.parse(rawdata);
  res.send(pokemons);
});
```

This code works perfectly when I fetch it in the HTML file:

```
    var parentDOM = document.getElementById("test");
    
    fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/pokemons")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => 
      {
        //console.log(data)
        data.forEach(element => 
        parentDOM.innerHTML += "Pokemon: "+element.name+" ID: " +element.id +"</br>"
        );

      });
```

but I am looking for a way to fetch only one ID at a time and send it to the client to a designed HTML file because I have 151 objects. I want to have a file, let's say pokemon.html and access to IDs using the browser - for instance when I go to http://localhost:8000/api/pokemon.html/2

To fetch all the objects from the json file I used pure JS and it worked. Is there a way to pass a parameter to a HTML file so I can then check the ID and fetch the specific json object?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want the Node.js app to serve the HTML file with an ID injected into the markup somewhere?

Comment: You can get the ID in the URL from the front-end JS using something like `location.href.split('/').pop()`, or use an HTML template in the back-end, where you inject the ID so that it's readily available in the front-end

Comment: It sounds more like you want to send an ID to the API. This is covered in most ExpressJS tutorials. Unrelated, but you may not want to read the JSON file on every request.

Comment: @MattHamann - Yes, that's exactly what I want - but I don't want the Node.js application to do it, I want the user to send the request to the API and then get the specific json object. I just don't want the server do it, I want everything to be on the client side, and I need to make one HTML file that will print the pokemons by the ID.

Comment: @DaveNewton thanks for the answer but that's not what I meant. I want to have a static HTML file and to be able to send a parameter to it, and then fetch the object from the API using the parameter I got from the client. Is that possible? hope I was clear enough.

Comment: So you want to send an ID from the URL to the API. The API needs the ID in order to know what data to send back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can define parameters in your url

```
app.get("/api/pokemons/:id", function (req, res) {
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  let rawdata = fs.readFileSync("assets/pokemons.json");
  let pokemons = JSON.parse(rawdata);
  pokemons.filter(x=> x.id == req.params.id)
  res.send(pokemons);
});
```

Edit: i think I missunderstood the question to read parameters in the html file
you can do if you have an url
`http://localhost:8000/api/pokemon.html?id=2`

```
const queryString = window.location.search;
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
urlParams.get('id')//will return 2
```

if the url is like this and your certain
`http://localhost:8000/api/pokemon.html/2`
you could just split

```
const queryString = window.location.href
let parts = queryString.split('/')
let id = parts[parts.length-1]
```

Comment: Thank you but that's not what I meant. I know how to get the specific object but I want the HTML file to be able to show it. I have a HTML file named "pokemon.html" and I want it to get a parameter - I want it to fetch the new object every time. Like I do in PHP - $_GET

Comment: you are great! it worked. This is exactly what I needed but is there a way to do it shorter, for example like this: HTTP://localhost:8000/pokemons/2 instead of writing the id etc? and still be able to show it as a HTML file?

Comment: if you do js wont know what parameter, but if you know the end is always the number you want you could just split like someone suggested

Comment: By the way, is there a way to remove the need to add the .html? I only have 2 files and I want it to automatically know that I only serve html files

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232569/discussion-between-or-nakash-and-breezer).